# Why do nattokinase and serratiopeptidase remain effective when given orally, but not insulin?

Tags: proteins, digestion

Why do nattokinase and serratiopeptidase not break down in the stomach and intestines?

Article says that serratiopeptidase is absorbed in rats intestines after oral intake - https://iubmb.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1470-8744.1994.tb00308.x

Comment: Added reference to the body of the question, thanks